# Request session object is null if string parameter end with a file extension

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, action-filter

I have an action with which my users can donwload a file. The URL look like this :

```
http://mywebsite.lan/report/GetReport/reportname.xlsx
```

For the server to handle filename-like parameter, I've had to add this in my `web.config` :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The action in itself works pretty well, the user call the URL and the server return the file in parameter.

I have an authorization filter on the controller which handle this request which handle all my authentication check and authorization loading process and an action filter on the action which check for a specific permission. Both those filter use the Session object to store user info and rights.

The problem is that, when using this url, the session object is null in the action filter, making them crash when trying to access create keys on it. Nevertheless, the session object exist when in the action itself.

After some tracking, I've found that by adding a tailing / to the url, the session object was back again :

```
http://mywebsite.lan/report/GetReport/reportname.xlsx/
```

I can't seem to be able to find the root cause of this.

Has anyone else faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by adding the following lines to my the web.config

```
 <modules>
  <remove name="Session"/>
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</modules>
```

I think by default the Session module is configured with the "managedHandler" pre-condition.

`<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />`

and by default .xlst is not associated with a managed handler and Session module does not run for .xslt.

When you add "/" at the end of the URL I think "Default Document" logic triggers in somewhere, the default document is probably a Default.aspx or some such and it turns on the Session module. This is a pure guess, I did not verify.

Or alternatively you can probably associate .xslt with a managed handler (System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory) in IIS -> Handler Mappings. This should be probably even better because I do not like it how Session module now triggers in for every request on our web site, but I did not try it because in our case there was no defined extension to associate with.